# Is there a way to revert to a previous commit in VS code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to revert to a previous git commit in VS code?

I know I can see the changes between commits and the differences in the working tree but I want to know how to reset to the previous commit in visual studio code.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

With the source control icon selected, if you then click the ellipsis ... at the top right.

With v1.48 you will see a list of options for submenus: under `Commit` is `Undo Last Commit`.  Under `Changes` is `Discard All Changes`.

[image: git submenus]

Comment: but what that does is it even puts the changes that are now done to the previous commit . I want to reset back to the previous commit

Comment: There is also a "Discard All Changes" - that would undo all changes since the last commit - is that what you want?

Comment: `ctrl + shift + p`, type with 'discard', you can discard changes in single file or multiple files at once.

Comment: what if the commit is already pushed? is there a way that we can removed the last push in VS code?

Answer (score 41):

Provided that you have [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension installed you should be able to simply select "Restore" action from selected "File history" commit.

[image: GitLens Restore file from File History]

Comment: I am not sure but I followed this suggestion on a binary diagram file (draw.io) and it appears that the restored file is much older than the one from the last commit. Just to be sure, I would like to revert to an older specific commit with a commit id. Do you happen to know a way to do that using GitLens or a git bash command?

Answer (score 17):

I use [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) for that:

1. In the source control tab, open `File History`.
2. Choose your commit, then right-click `Commit`.
3. Click on `Revert Commit...`.

[image]

Comment: gitLens is an excellent product, it also shows the command in the terminal, so you can learn how to use it

Comment: Can you use this feature in free plan of GitLens?

Comment: @MehmedB Only with public and local repositories.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this option in the Gitlens "commits" section to reset any number of previous (local) commits: just right click on the commit you would like to reset your current local branch

[image]

Then a list appears to allow you to choose a suitable reset option, as usual:

[image]

In recent vscode (1.51.1 currently installed) Gitlens extension has been integrated in the source control side view, by the way, instead of having its own button in the sidebar as before.

Answer (score 9):

In vscode press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd>, type `git undo`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: this is easy and quick