# git revert never worked once on this project

Tags: html, git, visual-studio-code

I'm writing the code for this website.

When I do git revert, it never returns the code I had on a particular commit.

Not even once!

I always have to manually rewrite it.

Is it VS code or am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: Please, post the full command history.

Answer (score 0):

It depend which "revert" you are suing on VSCode.

Using GitLens, as mentioned here, you would use the actual [`git revert` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert), which is about cancelling a specific commit diff/patch, not about restoring a past commit.
It creates a new commits in which the negative image of the commit patch is applied.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdtSb.png]

If you wanted the exact same past commit, you would need [to reset to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65001071/6309)

[image: reset]

But that would then possibly mean a force push, which can be inconvenient if you are several contributors working on the same repository/branch.

In any case, select `Terminal: Focus on the Terminal view`, then `Output`, then "`Git`" (in the dropdown list): you will see the exact git command you are doing through VSCode when "reverting".