# How to undo a pushed commit from remote and local branch in VS Code?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I got stuck. I accidently commited and pushed to the wrong branch. Is there a way to go back? Or to undo that and push it to the right branch? **How do you do it in Visual Studio Code?**. I researched and I need to do the 'revert' option.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to revert to a previous commit in VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913896/is-there-a-way-to-revert-to-a-previous-commit-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1):

You can revert change using `git revert [commit_hash]` follow by `git push origin [branch_name]`

If not sure about your commit_hash value. Check using `git log` command.

Here are two links on how to revert using VS Code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-manage-repository?view=vs-2022

[Is there a way to revert to a previous commit in VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913896/is-there-a-way-to-revert-to-a-previous-commit-in-vs-code)