# I accidentally turned a folder into a git repository while opening it in VS Code. How can I revert this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I created over 10K+ changes in VS Code, status pending.

I want to get rid of them

How can I fix this?

[image: vscode]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to revert to a previous commit in VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913896/is-there-a-way-to-revert-to-a-previous-commit-in-vs-code)

Comment: you most likely have created a `.git` folder in your home directory, remove that, and don't open your home folder as a workspace folder

Comment: @user has tried the `git init` command in the wrong folder (home directory)

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for you based on your screenshot and the fact that you're on Windows:

Open your file explorer, find the `C:\Users\vavro\.git` directory (which stores all the info git keeps about a local repository), and delete it. To see that folder, you *might* need to toggle a checkbox in your File Explorer View settings- Show Hidden Items.

You can also do this via commandline. Ex. If you have Git Bash installed, `rm -rf ~/.git`.

If you want to avoid this happening when using VS Code with git installed, avoid opening your home folder as a workspace folder in VS Code.